# How to test if a string is an expression, or just a string?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am having trouble trying to convert an `InArgument<String>` for use in a custom Activity designer (rehosted). I have gotten this to work very nicely for datatypes such as `float` and `int`. The idea is to have the user enter the settings in the most intuitive way. For example, using a `TextBox` the user can enter a literal number (i.e. 9) or a VB expression (i.e. the variable `num`). Here is an example converter:

```
public class InArgumentIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ModelItem modelItem = value as ModelItem;
        if (modelItem != null)
        {
            InArgument<int> inArgument = modelItem.GetCurrentValue() as InArgument<int>;

            if (inArgument != null)
            {
                Activity<int> expression = inArgument.Expression;
                VisualBasicValue<int> vbexpression = expression as VisualBasicValue<int>;
                Literal<int> literal = expression as Literal<int>;

                if (literal != null)
                {
                    return literal.Value.ToString();
                }
                else if (vbexpression != null)
                {
                    return vbexpression.ExpressionText;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string itemContent = (string)value;
        InArgument<int> inArgument = null;
        try
        {
            int literal = int.Parse(itemContent);
            inArgument = new InArgument<int>(literal);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            VisualBasicValue<int> vbArgument = new VisualBasicValue<int>(itemContent);
            inArgument = new InArgument<int>(vbArgument);
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your number is too big!");
        }

        return inArgument;
    }
}
```

The key here seems to be that I can detect if the value in the text box is a literal or an expression by using the appropriate `Parse()` method, but there seems to be no way to test if a string is a regular old string or an expression.

Parsing the value as a literal breaks expressions, but parsing as an expression forces quotes around the value in the textbox for literal values.

So, my question is, how does one test if an expression is a literal string or an expression?

**Edit:**

To add clarification, the end result I am trying to achieve is that the user can enter either a literal string or an expression into a `Windows.Controls.TextBox`, without having to use quotes for literal values. (I tried to add images to make this more clear, but  I guess I don't have enough reputation yet, so ASCII art will have to do).

Should appear:

```
  +-------------------------+          +-----------------------------+
  | Some Literal value      |    or    | foo + "Some expression"     |
  +-------------------------+          +-----------------------------+
```

Should NOT appear as: (occurs when parsing as an expression, i.e. VisualBasicValue)

```
  +-------------------------+          +-----------------------------+
  | "Some Literal value"    |    or    | foo + "Some expression"     |
  +-------------------------+          +-----------------------------+
```

Should NOT appear as: (occurs when parsing as an literal, i.e. Literal)

```
  +-------------------------+          +-----------------------------+
  | Some Literal value      |    or    | "foo + "Some expression""   |
  +-------------------------+          +-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code isn't totally understandable what you're doing, but I guess you're inventing the wheel here.

Are you using a normal WPF TextBox? There's available an [ExpressionTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.expressiontextbox.aspx) which does exactly what you're describing. No need to wrote custom converters.

Check this example: [How to create a Custom Activity Designer with Windows Workflow Foundation (WF4)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2011/08/14/how-to-create-a-custom-activity-designer-with-windows-workflow-foundation-wf4.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response @jota, but ExpressionTextBox does not really resolve the problem I am trying to solve. I edited my question to try to make it more clear the behavior I am looking for.